# Maven: eliminate [INFO] lines but not "real" output?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I would like to `mvn help:effective-pom` and display only the XML representing the POM.

When I run `mvn -q help:effective-pom` to filter the `[INFO]` and related lines, it also disables printing of the POM.

Is there an option to display the POM only, without the `[INFO]` lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to read the [documentation of maven-help-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) which offers the possibility to write the result into a file.

So you can call the `effective-pom` goal like this:

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=TheFileYouLikeToHaveTheOutputIn.xml
```

Comment: Plus One for pointing to the documentation as well as providing the answer!